# Schutz A First Course in GR. Fig 1.14 "a simple calculation"

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime

Schutz discusses why, when two observers move relative to each other, each considers the other's clocks to run slow. He sets up figure 1.14 (around page 20-22 depending on the edition). You can see the relevant figure and discussion if you "look inside" on amazon and search for "simple calculation".

In the paragraph beginning "But $\overline O$ need no accept them", he says "a simple calculation shows this to be at $ t = (1-v^2)^{1/2}$".

What is that "simple calculation"?

Comment: to go to amazon or a library to answer a probably simple question is really demanding a lot

Comment: I suggest you first learn about special relativity from books or other resources devoted purely to that.

Comment: I figured it out myself. I was misdirecting myself initially by misreading a comma in Schutz's book.

Comment: So the advice to learn about SR was completely wrong and unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly standard, and I don't think it necessary to refer to Schutz, although I am not sure whether you have incorrectly transcribed his result, or whether he had set the time on the other clock to $1$. This is how I do the calculation in my book Light After Dark III: The Mathematics of Gravity and Quanta

[image]

A spacecraft, moving at speed $v$ relative to the Earth, passes close by the
Earth (figure 7.4). The spacecraft and the Earth both set clocks to zero at the
moment the spacecraft passes the Earth. After time $t$ on the Earth clock, the
spacecraft has travelled distance $vt$ in Earth based coordinates. A radar signal reflected by the spacecraft at time $t$ would have been sent at time  $t - vt$, and will return at time $t + vt$. Using Doppler shift, if the Earth sent signals at time $t-vt$ the spacecraft will receive it at time

$T = k(t-vt)$

on the spacecraft clock. Applying the Doppler shift for the signal coming back,

$t+vt = kT = k^2(t-vt)$

Rearranging,

$k^2 = \frac{1+v}{1-v}$

Substituting for $k$ gives the time on the spacecraft’s clock,

$T = t \sqrt{1-v^2}$

So, the spacecraft clock appears to go slow in the Earth frame. Similarly the
Earth clock appears to go slow in the spacecraft frame. This is possible because
the Earth and the spacecraft have different notions of the simultaneity of events
remote from their own clocks.

Comment: Your answer appears to be copied from some other source.  Please cite your sources.

Comment: We actively discourage images of maths and text.  Physics SE prefers the use of actual text and [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for maths.  It's not uncommon for posts using images like instead of Mathjax to be downvoted by some people.